# How to asynchronously send emails?

Tags: go, asynchronous

I have an endpoint that serves requests. In the request flow, the endpoint needs to generate and send an email notification (let's name the code `sendEmail()`). I want the endpoint to asynchronously call `sendEmail()`. The endpoint should not wait for `sendEmail()`.

The code is like:

```
func (s *server) MyEndpoint(ctx context.Context, request *MyRequest) (MyResponse, error) {
  // other logic

  // async
  sendEmail()
  // end async

  // other logic - should not wait for the response from sendEmail
  
  return getMyResponse(), nil
}
```

How do I do this? I realize this may be basic, but I'm new to Go and want to make sure I follow best practices.

Comment: You can do `go sendEmail()` to run `sendEmail` in another goroutine.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks. It's that simple?

Comment: If you realize this is basic... did you have a look at the documentation available online? If so, what did you find? Have you made an attempt to solve the problem? If so, what was the issues you ran into? If not, have a look at [ask].

Comment: @onepiece, normally, you would want to handle errors, wait for completion, etc. so it can be more involved. However, making an asynchronous call is just that simple.

Comment: You can try with a channel where you push all the email contents (you can create a struct where store all the mail requirement like email, body, and content) and handle this with a running goroutine that listens to the channel,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`go routines`](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1) you execute concurrent code. In your example, you want to fetch the response on the return. One way of doing this is by using *channels*.

You do it by passing a channel to both functions, where one produces the data and the other consumes it. There's a great article about channels [here](https://go101.org/article/channel.html). It would look like this (note I used interface{} type here, if you got a concrete type it is the preferable way)

```
func (s *server) MyEndpoint(ctx context.Context, request *MyRequest) (MyResponse, error) {
  // other logic

  // async
  c := make(chan interface{})
  go sendEmail(c)
  // end async

  // other logic - should not wait for the response from sendEmail
  // getMyResponse must happen only after sendEmail has done
  return getMyResponse(c), nil
}
```

Comment: In my post, `getMyResponse()` actually doesn't depend on the response from `sendEmail()`. Does that mean I can simply do `go sendEmail()`, without using channels?

Comment: Yes. It's important to note that if the main program exits, and sendEmail hasn't finished - it will be terminated.

Comment: "the main program" does that refer to the main function that runs `s *server`? If so, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @onepiece yes, it's what inside your main function.